# Avoid repeating config between Conan profile and CMake

Tags: cmake, conan

I have been learning Conan for a personal project, and I have a question that I haven't been able to answer from looking at the docs and examples.

There seems to be an awkward lack of interaction between Conan's "profiles" and CMake.  What I mean is: There are a number of different build parameters that must be manually kept in sync - running CMake with different parameters than the ones that were chosen during `conan install` will result in build errors.

To give a more concrete example, here are two of my configs and how I would use them to build:

```
$ cat ~/.conan/profiles/gcc_debug
[settings]
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=10
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Debug
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
$ export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
$ conan install ../src --profile gcc_debug
$ cmake ../src -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
$ cmake --build .
```

```
$ cat ~/.conan/profiles/clang_cl_release
[settings]
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.version=16
compiler.toolset=ClangCL
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

$ conan install ../src --profile clang_cl_release
$ cmake ../src -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -TClangCL
$ cmake --build . --config=Release
```

In the first example, I have to repeat `gcc` and `Debug`.
In the second one, I have to repeat `Visual Studio`, `16`, `ClangCL`, and `Release`.

Having to repeat myself so many times feels smelly, especially when these options are spread out across multiple long-running commands, and forgetting one just option can result in non-obvious error messages.  It also seems weird to me that Conan doesn't just enforce (override) the appropriate CMake vars when you call `cmake_basic_setup()`; it already knows what values it expects, and blows up if they don't match.

What is the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started looking into [`conan build`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/development/build.html), which seems promising.  I had originally skipped over this because it looked like it only applied to people who were publishing a Conan package, but now I'm thinking it is meant for consumers as well.  In fact, [this page](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/conanfile_py.html#conan-build) even explicitly mentions my problem statement:

> This `conan build` will use the settings used in the `conan install` which have been cached in the local `conaninfo.txt` and file in your build folder. This simplifies the process and reduces the errors of mismatches between the installed packages and the current project configuration. [...] Implementing and using the conanfile.py `build()` method ensures that we always use the same settings both in the installation of requirements and the build of the project, and simplifies calling the build system.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use Conan to setup all your external libraries and then use them from CMake. You can however do the other way around: Let CMake call Conan to install the external dependencies.

Example code from [How to launch conan install from cmake](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/cmake_launch.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(myproject CXX)

# Download automatically, you can also just copy the conan.cmake file
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
   message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
   file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/master/conan.cmake"
                  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

conan_cmake_run(REQUIRES Catch2/2.6.0@catchorg/stable
                BASIC_SETUP)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Comment: How are we supposed to decided what option is best suited to our case? (that is, setup Conan then call CMake versus letting cmake call conan?

Answer (score 2):

Let Conan handle all the gory details in its `build` function!

### Using new CMakeToolchain + CMakeDeps generators

**conanfile.py**

```py
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, cmake_layout

...

requires   = "fmt/7.1.3" # example requirement
generators = "CMakeToolchain", "CMakeDeps"

...

def layout(self):
    cmake_layout(self)

def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()

...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```cmake
cmake_minmum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED) # Find dependency brought by Conan

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} fmt::fmt)
```

**Terminal**:

```bash
$ conan install -if build/Release . # Add -pr <profile> here
$ conan build -if build/Release .
```

You don't have to manually export GCC every time, put it under the `[env]` section of your profile:

```bash
conan profile update "env.CC=/usr/bin/gcc" gcc_debug
```

### Using old cmake generator

⚠️ This is for Conan **v1.X**!

**conanfile.py**

```py
from conans import CMake

...

generators = "cmake"

...

def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()

...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```cmake
cmake_minmum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
set(CONAN_SYSTEM_INCLUDES ON) # Hide GCC/Clang warnings in third-party libs
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
conan_target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

**Terminal**:

```bash
$ conan install -if build/Release . # Add -pr <profile> here
$ conan build -bf build/Release .
```

Your default generator can be specified this way (only works with `cmake` generator):

```bash
conan profile update "env.CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja" gcc_debug
```

Answer (score 1):

See recommended conan usage: https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan

```
set(CONAN_PROFILE_NAME ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-${CMAKE_GENERATOR})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CONAN_CMD} profile new ${CONAN_PROFILE_NAME} --detect ERROR_QUIET)
conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

# REPEAT THIS FOR EACH OF YOUR REMOTES
conan_cmake_configure(REQUIRES zlib/1.2.0 GENERATORS cmake_find_package)
conan_cmake_install(PATH_OR_REFERENCE .
                BUILD missing
                REMOTE conancenter
                PROFILE ${CONAN_PROFILE_NAME}
                SETTINGS ${settings})
  
find_package(zlib)
```